# Is Assembly.LoadFrom keeping an open file handle?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I am loading another assembly using

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("path.exe");
```

and after that i cant seem to delete that exe from the file system. so i was wondering if this path keeps an open file handle and how i can close it?

Comment: Delete it *when*? When your program has finished or when it is still running?

Comment: @m0skit0: when it is still runnning. when i know that i wont need anything from this assembly anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is open until the assembly is unloaded from the appdomain.

If you really need to delete the file, load its content into memory. The use [`Assembly.Load(byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7.aspx) to load the assembly:

```
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead("path.exe"))
{
    byte[] rawAssembly = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(rawAssembly, 0, (int)stream.Length);
    Assembly.Load(rawAssembly);
}
```

Comment: and another question: if i happen to load the same assembly twice, will that open another file handle or will it reuse the first one?

Comment: You cant' unload it without unloading the whole appdomain. With `AppDomain.Unload()`.

Comment: You can't load the same assembly twice in the same AppDomain.

Comment: It's a _can't_. But it won't throw an exception. As the file is assembly loaded, it does need to load it again.

Answer (score 2):

By default, files will be locked, but .NET has a feature called Shadow Copies, in which it will make a copy of the assembly and load that instead. ASP.NET relies on this to enable web sites to be updated without running into these locking issues.

See this [Shadow Copying Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx) topic on MSDN for details.