# Load assembly without locking dll file

Tags: vb.net, dll

General overwiew is 
Many users run MyApp.exe file instaled locally on their PCs 
MyApp is launching different dll files. 
Each dll is a winform application. 
All dll's are located on network share.

I'm trying to load dll file without locking it.

```
Const srcfile As String = "\\NetworkLocation\MyDll.dll"            
Dim Asm As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(srcfile)
Dim Ftype As System.Type = FrmUsr.GetType("MyDll.FrmMain")
Dim Mf As System.Object = Activator.CreateInstance(Ftype)
Application.Run(Mf)
```

This works fine but it locks MyDll.dll file.

I can use

```
Dim Asm As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(srcfile))
```

But then I end up with error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'X' or one of its dependencies. Can't find the specified file.

The missing assembly is other DLL file which is referenced in "MyDll.File". All Dll's are in same folder (network location). Maybe inside MyDll i should reference this other dll in different way?

Comment: how large are those dll files? you could try reading the bytes of the files into the memory, and calling the LoadFrom overload that takes in a byte array.

Comment: do dlls have to be stored on network? why not distribute them along with the app?

Comment: Just loading an assembly the way you are will not "lock" the file. What do you mean by lock anyway? You aren't modifying the assembly in any way, and you just need read access. So it must be something else going on

Comment: @EmreBener dll are between 20KB to 10MB. If i load it as byte array it will not lock the dll? All are stored on network due to company security policy. I'm not able to distribute updates on local computers. Having all on network i just switch the dll and everybody have new version on next run.

Comment: @djv if i use 'LoadFrom' then as lonn as user uses the tool i can't delet or update the dll on network drive. It says that the file is in use.

Comment: @Sphinx yes, that would basically make a copy of the dll file in RAM and use that instead of connecting to the one stored on network. 20KB to 10MB sounds fine.

Comment: @Sphinx ah, well yes you won't be able to write (overwrite) the file if it is in use. That's not what this `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly` is talking about however, that's an assembly load failure, not related to updating your application i.e. `i can't delet or update the dll on network drive. It says that the file is in use`. What is your actual issue?

Comment: You can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17838414/832052) to load the assembly into memory

Comment: Quite a little tangent solution, and will take a little cooperation for IT department but is it feasible to run your app as a Remote Desktop Published App?  Saving you the overheads of loading these DLLs over the network at all